# Why does My Boolean variable Automatically switch?

Tags: c++, boolean

I have a program where players and enemies can attack each other in a loop and when health reaches zero, the bool `isDead` turns to true, and when both players or both enemies are dead then `allDead(c1, c2)` turns to true. When a character's isDead is true, then I skip their turn.  But I've been setting breakpoints and I notice that the character's isDead automatically turn to true even though they still have health. I looked everything over and I just don't understand what I'm missing. isDead has been initialized to false and all the lines associated with the variable are meant to check if its true or false. Could someone please help point out what i'm missing? Thank you.

isDead Function

```
bool Character::isDead() {
if (dead = true)
    return true;
}
```

Main

```
int main()
{


srand(time(NULL));  

PlayerCharacter* p1 = new PlayerCharacter();
PlayerCharacter* p2 = new PlayerCharacter();
EnemyCharacter* e1 = new EnemyCharacter();
EnemyCharacter* e2 = new EnemyCharacter();

p1->printCharacter();
p2->printCharacter();
e1->printCharacter();
e2->printCharacter();


string enemyTarget, playerTarget;

list<Character*> players;
list<Character*> enemies;

players.push_back(p1);
players.push_back(p2);
enemies.push_back(e1);
enemies.push_back(e2);


list<Character*>::iterator PinsertIt = players.begin();
list<Character*>::iterator EinsertIt = enemies.begin();



for (; PinsertIt != players.end() && EinsertIt != enemies.end(); ++PinsertIt, ++EinsertIt)
{

    listShuffle(players);
    listShuffle(enemies);

    if (*PinsertIt == p1)
    {
        if (!p1->isDead())////isDead switches to true when I reach this line
        {
            cout << "Player One. Choose your Target (1 or 2)" << endl;
            cin >> playerTarget;
            playerAttack(e1, e2, p1->currentWeapon, playerTarget);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << p1->firstName << " " << p1->lastName << " is dead" << endl;
        }
    }
    else if (*PinsertIt == p2)
    {
        if (!p2->isDead())
        {
            cout << "Player Two. Choose your Target (1 or 2)" << endl;
            cin >> playerTarget;
            playerAttack(e1, e2, p2->currentWeapon, playerTarget);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << p2->firstName << " " << p2->lastName << " is dead" << endl;
        }
    }


    if (*EinsertIt == e1)
    {

        if (!e1->isDead())
        {
            cout << "Enemy One ";
            enemyAttack(p1, p2, e1->currentWeapon);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << e1->firstName << " " << e1->lastName << " is dead" << endl;
        }
    }
    else if (*EinsertIt == e2)
    {
        if (!e2->isDead())
        {
            cout << "Enemy Two ";
            enemyAttack(p1, p2, e2->currentWeapon);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << e2->firstName << " " << e2->lastName << " is dead" << endl;
        }
    }



    if (allDead(p1, p2)) 
    {
        cout << "Game Over!" << endl;
    }
    else if (allDead(e1, e2)) 
    {
        cout << "You Win!" << endl;
    }
}




system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: should be ``if (dead == true)`` or ``if(dead)``, your code will assign ``true`` to ``dead`` that's why

Comment: I would make it `bool Character::isDead() {return dead;}` no need for an if() and you need to return in both the true and false conditions otherwise you have UB.

Comment: You should turn on your compiler warnings so you don't make mistakes like assignments in conditions.